# Why isn't atta translated as essence instead of self?

Tags: self, atta

In Buddhist philosophy, the Pali term 'atta' is frequently translated into English as 'self.' However, this translation can be misleading since in common English usage, 'self' often implies an inherent identity or individuality that the Buddhist concept of 'anatta' (not-self) seems to refute. Some might argue that 'essence' could be a more fitting translation, as it suggests the fundamental qualities of a person or thing. Given this, why do translators choose to use 'self' rather than 'essence' when translating 'atta' from Buddhist texts, especially when the term 'essence' might avoid the misconception of an enduring, independent self that Buddhism actually seeks to dispel?

Comment: the mods should do a better job of vetting questions

Comment: [Moderation policies for Questions](https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1558/254)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Buddha was not concerned with theories of 'essence'. The Buddha was concerned with the abandoning of ego attachment that brings agitation & suffering. This was made clear in the definition of 'anatta' in the 2nd Sermon.

> Therefore, surely, O monks, whatever form, past, future or present,
> internal or external, coarse or fine, low or lofty, far or near, all
> that form must be regarded with proper wisdom, according to reality,
> thus: '**This is not mine, this I am not, this is not my self**.'
>
> [SN 22.59](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/sn/sn22/sn22.059.mend.html)

Again:

> Suppose a person were to gather or burn or do as he likes with the
> grass, twigs, branches, & leaves here in Jeta's Grove. Would the
> thought occur to you, 'It's us that this person is gathering, burning,
> or doing with as he likes'?"
>
> "No, lord. Why is that? Because those things are not our self nor do
> they pertain to our self."
>
> "In the same way, monks, the eye is not yours: let go of it. Your
> letting go of it will be for your long-term happiness & benefit... The
> ear... The nose... The tongue... The body... The intellect is not
> yours: let go of it. Your letting go of it will be for your long-term
> happiness & benefit... Whatever arises in dependence on
> intellect-contact, experienced either as pleasure, as pain, or as
> neither-pleasure-nor-pain, that too is not yours: let go of it. Your
> letting go of it will be for your long-term happiness & benefit."
>
> [SN 35.101](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/sn/sn35/sn35.101.than.html)

Again:

> He does not assume consciousness to be the self, or the self as possessing consciousness, or consciousness as in the self, or the self as in consciousness. He is not seized with the idea that 'I am consciousness' or 'Consciousness is mine.' As he is not seized with these ideas, his consciousness changes & alters, but he does not fall into sorrow, lamentation, pain, distress, or despair over its change & alteration. This, householder, is how one is afflicted in body but unafflicted in mind.
>
> [SN 22.1](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/sn/sn22/sn22.001.than.html)

Comment: ok, ego attachment is self attachment. i get it.

Answer (score 0):

There is no essence. For example - What is the essence of Car ? Is it engine ? Engines change. First the horse or oxes used to pull carts then cycle came then gasoline engine came then petrol and diesel engine came and now electric engines are coming… Car can not be found in the engine. What is the essence of Car ? Is it tyres ? No . Is it the steering wheel ? No . Is it an abstract idea that anything that allows travel from one place to another is Car ? No.

There is no absolute essence of Car.
Similarly for human or animal or godly body. The essence can not be found.

Atta essentially tries to convey the essence only.Therefore  there is no need to replace Atta with essence.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know.  atta is peace.  so how can it be self?  how could it even be essence, unless essence is peace?

[Attadiipaa Sutta](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/sn/sn22/sn22.043.wlsh.html)

Comment: When peace is recognised. Then we a realise that there is peace but we also recognise that it was achieved through choice and intention. Choice and intention being impermanent, the peace is impermanent. Peace being impermanent. One is not attached to it.

Comment: maybe. absence is permanent(nicca). that's what i read anyway.

Answer (score 0):

There is a Pali word for 'essence', often translated as 'heartwood', which is 'sāra'.

> [sāra](https://suttacentral.net/define/s%C4%81ra?lang=en)
>
> essence; the pith of a tree; the choicest part. (adjective) essential; excellent; strong

In [SN 22.95](https://suttacentral.net/sn22.95/en/suddhaso?lang=en&reference=none&highlight=true), the word 'asāra' is found:

> Monks, when it is raining in autumn and large raindrops are falling on
> the water, a water-bubble might arise and vanish. A person with
> eyesight could see it, consider it and examine it. By seeing it,
> considering it and examining it, that person could determine that it
> was insubstantial, hollow and **essenceless (asāra)**. Monks, what essence could
> there be in a water-bubble? Monks, in exactly the same way, a monk
> sees, considers and examines any feeling – whether past, present or
> future, internal or external, coarse or subtle, inferior or superior,
> far or near. By seeing it, considering it and examining it, one
> determines that it is insubstantial, hollow, and essenceless **(asāra)**. Monks,
> what **essence (sāra)** can there be in feelings?